# How to add constrain validation on entity_create

Tags: 8, entities

So in my BaseFieldDefinition I have this below

```
 $fields['name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
  ->setLabel(t('Name'))
  ->setDescription(t('The name of the Crypto entity.'))
  ->addConstraint('UniqueField')
```

And I was hoping this would make this "name" field unique when creating new enteties. It does when I try to do that in UI, but when programmatically making new entities it is just ignored.

```
 $crypto = entity_create('crypto', array(
  'name' => "Dai",
  'status' => '1',
));
$crypto->save();
```

So should I use some other method for creating entities or do I need to add some manual validation here?

Also extra question, how do I find list of "addConstraint" values that are present in core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities aren't validated automatically when saved via the API. (I'd be interested in knowing more about why not.) See [the validation API docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/entity-validation-api-overview) for examples of validating a field and a whole entity:

```
$violations = $entity->field_text->validate(); // single field
$violations = $entity->validate();             // whole entity

if ($violations->count() > 0) {
  // Validation failed.
}
```

To find all possible constraints, look for anything extending (possibly indirectly) `\Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint`.

Comment: That is it, thanx.